# show/hide() changing block level element's width/behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really stuck with this one and have no idea how to solve this, I use jQuery ~ usually without too many problems. But as I don't write JS I do get stuck :(
I've searched and searched for answers and tried out too many approaches and not getting anywhere... :( I bet I'm missing something very obvious or simple, hoping someone might be able to help...

ok - the problem:
I have a website for my webdesign course which shows the main nav in the left column. For the smallest screens (ie below 420px width) - I want to hide the menu, displaying a 'view menu' link instead which uses the jQuery toggle() function to show / hide the menu on demand.

Initially, I did this via a straight forward toggle alone - all fine - apart from the issue that the menu would remain hidden once it was shown and hidden once on a small screen. If the window is resized - it would remain hidden.

That was the problem I set out to solve, mentioning it here as I might be going down the wrong path entirely here ~ doubting whether I'm doing this in the right way :'(

Now - I am using JS to hide the 'view menu' link for all screens, only showing on screens smaller than 420px. I've added the resize() function as well to allow more dynamic behaviour.
Everything is working as intended for the showing and hiding of my menu - BUT....

The toggle link itself is set to display:block - when the window loads below 420px, it displays as intended: set to block (spanning full width for a nicely solid active link) with the text centred.
However, when I load the page at larger window size, then resize to below 420px width - the toggle link seems to become inline? Not at full width any longer, text appears to be left aligned as the element no longer is full width...?!

I've tried setting width in CSS, tried resetting with via resize() element, via assigning 100% width via JS....nothing is working - I'm sure I'm missing something....

I'd really appreciate any pointers or thoughts ~ feel like I'm missing something very basic here....

the website: [webeyedea.info](http://webeyedea.info)

here's my JS code, following the link to jQuery:

```
// check for window size size on page load and show relevant content only 
$(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 420) {
        $('#toggle-nav').hide();
        $('nav ul').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#toggle-nav').show();
        $('nav ul').hide();
    }
});
// check for window resize - show nav again for larger screens after hiding
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 420) {
        $('#toggle-nav').hide();
        $('nav ul').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#toggle-nav').show();
        $('nav ul').hide();
    }
});

// show menu (smallest screens)
$('nav #toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('nav ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.  
    });
    $('ul').addClass('view');
});
```

UPDATE: SEE [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eyedea/HWmp3/1/)

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle with this now as it might be easier to see what is going wrong - [toggle menu](http://jsfiddle.net/eyedea/HWmp3/1/)               


on window resize - the display inline get applied, overriding my display block from the CSS - this does not happen when window is loaded at a small screen size...

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.show()` on an element it sets the display property to the previous value and if it does not exist I believe it takes the default browser value which may be `inline` in your case. Try setting it explicitly to `block`.

Comment: Thanks, Andre - tried that... well, I tried via CSS, setting the width to display block + even adding in 100% - no luck :(

Then I tried setting width to 100% via JS - no luck either ;(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is doing what here since I don't have a mobile to test it, but could you try to replace your hide/show with a css function that toggle between display:none and display:block ?

Like this :

```
$('#toggle-nav').css('display','none');
$('#toggle-nav').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, Alexandre - I thought it might be best to both show and hide via JS - to ensure that the menu would remain visible if JS is disabled?

Comment: Alexandre, ah,... hadn't tried that yet - thanks for the snippet.

But it didn't work :( when I replaced y show and hide for the #toggle-nav - the menu again remains hidden when window is resized to larger size...

Comment: I told you it was with that code :P I wasn't quite sure to write the whole code for you since I'm writing this from my job. I knew it was display: none and block :) enjoy !

Comment: Alexandre ~ thanks for taking the time ;) really appreciate it.     


sorry if I reply a bit slowly, new to using Stackoverflow - been reading and learning a lot on here - but not used to the posting - yet :)

Answer (score 0):

See my revised fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HWmp3/9/
I tested this on the iphone simulator and it works. My test was I copied the codes to a local file and tested. I put all the js inside of document.ready

make sure you have the meta in the header

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thanks, Huangism ~ tried that and it's not making any difference at all...  :( I really don't understand this at all - other than the fact that an inline style gets applied, setting my link to inline, see quick [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/6DXc9ouurdz).      



if the page loads at smallest screen - no inline CSS, all fine...  :(

Comment: did you change something? I just checked the site in FF and when I resize it is showing the inline css as block and it is working as you wanted

Comment: yeah, I did - I've been working on trying to fix this with various combinations - with no luck....  I can get it to work for the desktop browsers - but the toggle fails on the iPhone :( so still no solution that works properly...

Comment: Huangism ~ just to report back, tried the exact code from your fiddle now, thanks for that. I think I did have this version before - all working fine for the desktop browsers :)     but still not working when tested on the iPhone, now completely broken (not even the toggle on/off happens). Thanks for your suggestions :) will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

**ALMOST ! NOT SOLVED**

one solution, thanks to Vlad Radulescu (on [Forrst](http://forrst.com/posts/help_stuck_with_jQuery_I_think_show_hide_ch-UGx)) ~ via this [jsfiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/pacMakaveli/HWmp3/4/embedded/result/)

```
$('a#toggle-nav').css('display','none');

// Show the menu if Window width is less than 420
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 420 ) {                    
        $('#toggle-nav').css('display','none');
        $('nav ul').show();                 
    }
    else {
        $('#toggle-nav').css('display','block');
        $('nav ul').hide();
    }            
});

// Slide the Menu on smaller screens
$('nav #toggle-nav').click(function() {
        $('nav ul').slideToggle('slow');                
});
```

Comment: oh I think that's what Alexandre meant, except he did not provide the full code

Comment: well, it's not working properly still.....
I was half way there thanks to your tips here — but the above version works ok on window resize - does not work properly when the window is loaded at small screensize, ie < 420px.

and it doesn't work on the iPhone (only mobile I have available for testing at the moment) - toggle link shows up, show/hide broken :(

Comment: one issue I see right away with the above code is the display none is declared outside, and you probably placed it after your first function where the >420 is. So it will hide it when you start with less than 420

Comment: this worked well enough apart from not working at all in the iPhone ~ and I just went with the recommended code, did try without it but it was glitchy in FF so I left that in there. I'll keep at it - must be solvable... :-\